# In Pine Script, is there a way to programatically force a script to execute through set of bars more than once?

Tags: pine-script

I've been working with Pine Script for a while now creating different indicators and strategies. I am aware that an indicator or strategy script executes automatically for each bar in the time interval plotted.

Is there a way a single script can automatically execute across all bars more than once, each time for slightly different parameter values?

For example, say I have a script that executes with input parameters x=1 and y=1. The script will be executed with these inputs for each bar. Can I do this, then have the script re-execute for x=1 and y=2, then x=1, y=3, etc, automatically across all bars each time, and then at the end score an accumulated  result for all iterations across all the bars?

I have tried putting a nested set of "for" loops in my script, but the problem is I don't want all the x and y inputs iterated through on each bar. I want to execute it on all bars with a given set of input values for x and y till the end of the bars, before re-executing with the next set of input values across all the bars again.

I have tried triggering a re-execution with the "security" function, but could not get it to re-trigger.

Am I correct in concluding from my experience with Pine Script so far that this kind of functionality is not supported?

Thanks,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. We have a feature request to implement re-execution requests from within a script, but it's only a suggestion for the moment.

[These](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#events-triggering-the-execution-of-a-script) are the conditions triggering re-execution of a script.

Comment: Thank-you so much